# Custom Calcuator

Tags: excel, calculator, calculation

Looking to see how to create a custom calculator, to pick from the top row (Resin Temp) and the column to the left (Ambient Temp)  to = to the numerical value that corresponds example: Resin Temp 50 - Ambient Temp 59 = 0.175.
[image]

Trying to create a simple calculator to use to find chemical additives needed.
If Ambient temp is between x & y  - and Resin temp is between x & y = to additives needed.

Comment: Seems and `IF` statement combined with an `AND` would do the trick. What have you tried and how does it fail to achieve the desired outcome?

Comment: Simplify your approach.  Each range of Ambient temp is 5 deg., each range of Resin Start Temp is 2 degrees.  With this in mind all you need to do is convert each temp to its relevant range 1(st row would be 0, 2nd would be 4, 3rd would be 9, etc.; 1st column would be 35, 2nd would be 37, 3rd would be 39, etc.)  and then use an Index/Match formula to find the intersection of the 2 values.